# How to detect moving object?

Tags: ros, sensor

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi peers!

I would like to know how can I make a robot detect a moving object and calculate out the speed of the moving object. Can this be done with a laser scanner or does this require other sensors? Is there any package on ROS that can do this?

Thanks for any advices.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/60370/how-to-detect-moving-object?/) by [Rookiebot](https://answers.ros.org/users/3536/rookiebot/) on ROS Answers with karma: 45 on 2013-04-09

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Amal](https://answers.ros.org/users/3346/amal/) on 2013-04-10**:
may can use color tracking, such as in gesture recognition ... this for tracking and can edit in algorithm to calculate the speed

**Comment by [Ashesh Goswami](https://answers.ros.org/users/8051/ashesh-goswami/) on 2014-01-14**:
Hey..I have just started working on a similar topic..wanted to know how you had proceeded with the problem of moving obstacle detection using laser scanner..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is this what you are looking for? http://www.willowgarage.com/blog/2012/01/17/tracking-3d-objects-point-cloud-library?page=30

---

Originally posted by [yigit](https://answers.ros.org/users/2389/yigit/) with karma: 796 on 2013-04-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0